# passing a JSON file in event: event cannot read keys, only values

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless-framework

so I have this simple code:

```
module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('event init', event.resource);
  console.log('message', event.message);
  console.log('EVENTS', event);
};
```

and I get this on my logs:

```
INFO    event init /get-quotation
INFO    message undefined
INFO    EVENTS { resource: '/get-quotation', isBase64Encoded: false }henlo"\n}',api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',3' ],t)' ],',
```

and I pass this body via Postman:

```
{
    "message":"henlo"
}
```

I used to code in AWS Lambda and when I call `event.message`, "henlo" will be the value but here it does not, it says `undefined` so I logged the whole event and as you can see when I console.log the whole event, I can see the "henlo" as part of the log but the key "message" is not there. how can I call `"henlo"`?

This is a Post Request too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a simple POST request using a JSON as the body, that's how I usually get the body

```
const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
```

Then you can use different ways to get its keys and vaues:

Object.keys

```
const keys = Object.keys(body);
```

Simply accessing the properties of body

```
const message = body.message;
```

or object destructuring

```
const { message } = body.message
```

**EDIT: adding info for lambda invoked using an event file**

In that case I usually do

```
const body = JSON.parse(event)
```

instead of

```
const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
```

Rest remains the same

Hope it helps!